# Twitter button do not append site URL

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, twitter-button

```
<a class='twitter-share-button' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My%20Message' data-size='large' data-url=''>Tweet</a>
```

This works great, EXCEPT it adds "http://localhost:3000" at the end of my tweet, even though I specify `data-url=''`.

How can I get it to not add the URL of the current site at the end?

Comment: Have you tried removing `data-url` entirely?

Comment: Yes I just tried again and it still appends the URL to the end of the message.

Comment: For the href, try this instead: `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My%20Message&url=/`. It seems to override the URL and not include it.

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to add that as a solution, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a class='twitter-share-button' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My%20Message&url=/' data-size='large'>Tweet</a>
```

If you specify a url of / as a query param, it won't include a url in the tweet. I'm not quite sure why it works that way, but it does.